# window.open not working in Intel XDK

Tags: inappbrowser, intel-xdk

Im creating a web app and i have a jquery function to open a link :

```
window.open(_url, "_self", 'width=800, height=600');
```

this works on browsers but not on the Intel XDK. Does window.open not work on web apps?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your web app is accessible in browser. is it?

Answer (score 1):

Use **_blank** instead of **_self**, this will open a popup like window with the app (InApp-browser), here is a working sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Window.open</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
        function openwin(){
            window.open('http://intel.com', '_blank', '');
        }
    </script>        
</head>
<body> 
    <button onclick="openwin()">window open</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use `_system` when opening a link on Android that can be handled natively e.g.

`mapUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=...&saddr=...',
window.open(encodeURI(mapsUrl), '_system');`

I get a `Your ... app has stopped working message.` otherwise.